# 3 Cards drawn from 52-card desk, probability of getting 2 clubs and 1 heart

Tags: probability

I worked this problem as follows, but it does not agree with the answer given in the answer sheet:  13C2 (for the clubs) * 13C1 (for the heart)/52C3

I get 39/850, but the answer gets 13/68.  Answers are not even close and I have to admit that my answer "seems" low.

Thoughts?

Comment: Your expression  $\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{1}/\binom{52}{3}$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression  $\dfrac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{52}{3}}$ is correct.

A little thought will show that $\frac{13}{68}$ is much too high. There are $12$ ways we can choose which suit to have two of, and which to have $1$ of. And that's not taking into account the $3$ different suit hands, and the one-suit hands.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is the correct one. The other answer is roughly $0.2$, which can't possibly be correct because there are 4 choices for which suit gets 2 cards and then 3 choices for which suit gets 1 card, and these are all disjoint cases so the answer can't be any higher than $1/12$.

Comment: Thank you SO very much for taking the time to answer.  I was concerned that I didn't understand these problems which will definitely be on the test tomorrow.